# Is it possible to transfer ps3 data to xbox one for destiny?

Tags: ps3, destiny, xbox-one

I used to play destiny on my Ps3 and got to a really high level on most of my characters. I have been talking to my friends about getting a next gen console and they want me to get an xbox one but I don't want to lose all of the things I have worked ages for. Is it possible that I can move the destiny data from my Ps3 to a xbox one?

Answer (score -1):

No both use different format to save progress. As xbox one runs on Microsoft made os and ps3 runs on sony made os. You can only use console of its own family. That is ps3 save is compatible with ps4 and xbox 360 save is compatible with xbox one. You cannot make them read save of other family (ps3 and xbox one).

Comment: You are incorrect. While saves are compatible in their own respective family, this has nothing to do with being able to "read" saves. It just happens that Bungie keeps the state persistent across console families as your account is persisted online rather than locally.